# To find the number of zeroes

Tags: calculus, functions

P1 - Given $f (x) = x^ {3} + ax^ {2} +6x -1$ has critical point at $x=-2$, then how many real solutions has $f (x) =0$?

MY Attempt regarding is that first i have found value of a which is 9\2 by setting -2 in derivative , thean i also see that f (2) is positive and f(-1) is negative so one root is there between them for sure .Also this can be seen by using corollory of IVT .But how can i be sure of other roots ?

Given $f(x) = xsinx + cosx$ , i have to find number of zeroes .Any hints for this problem .Thanks

Comment: Problem 2: infinity, plot it.

Comment: What is the other solution to $f'(x) = 0$? And which value does $f$ take at that point?

Comment: @Raclette sorry not got what you are tryirng to say

Comment: The equation $f'(x) = 0$ has two solutions, of which $-2$ is one. Which is the other one? If you know the value of $f$ at its critical points, then you know the number of roots. It's three if these values has opposite signs, and one if they have the same sign.

Comment: @Raclette the other solution is to be found out by plugging in a in derivative of f and then solving quadratic

Comment: @Raclette other value is -1

Comment: @Raclette do i haveto use corollary of rolles theoremhere ?

Comment: Perfect! And what is $f(-1)$ and $f(-2)$?

Comment: Both are negative values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have found that $a=\frac 92$, so the derivative being $3x^2-9x+6$ it also cancels for $x=-1$. So, now compute the value of the function at the critical points $$f(-2)=-3$$ $$f(-1)=-\frac{7}{2}$$ So, at both minimum and maximum, the function values are negative. Then only one real root is possible and, since by inspection $f(0)=-1$ and $f(1)=\frac{21}{2}$, the root should be positive, definitely smaller than $0$.

For your second problem, you could rewrite $x \sin(x)+\cos(x)=0$ as $x=-\cot(x)$ and consider the intersection of the two curves. Function $\cot(x)$ being undefined for $x=k\pi$, you have an infinite number of solutions, closer and closer to $k \pi$ (just smaller than).

Comment: Don't we have to see  hange in sign of f when going from little bit less of -2 to little bit more of -2 , then we will be able to decide whether it is maximum or minimum

Comment: smaller than $0$ and positive? how can that be?

Comment: i wonder that i was not downvoted

Comment: @claude Leibovici how can you say about max min

Comment: Look at the signs of the derivative and so, identify that $-2$ correponds to a local maximum and $-1$ to a local minimum.

Answer (score 1):

plugging $-2$ in $f'(x)$ we get $a=\frac{9}{2}$ and we have $f'(x)=3x^2+9x+6$ and $f''(x)=6x+9$ plugging $x=-2$ in the second derivative we get $f''(-2)=-3<0$ and thus we have a local maximum at $(-2;-3)$ further we have for $x=-1$ a local minimum thus for $x>-1$ the function is strictly monotomously increasing and we have exactly one zero point,
since $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\infty$